# Prevent div box from spacing automatically

Tags: html, css

```css
<style>
#stitched {
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: grey;
   width: 300px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px grey, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px grey;
   font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<td class="thead"><span class="smalltext"><strong>Player Control Panel</strong></span></td>
<tr>
<td class="trow1">

 <h1 style="font-size: 35px; text-align: center;">Player Control Panel</h1>
 
 <div id="stitched">
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-5x" style="text-align: center;"></i>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Create your new character account</h2>
 </div>
 
 <div id="stitched">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-5x" style="text-align: center;"></i>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Delete your existing character account</h2>
 </div>
</td>
```

Aforementioned is my code. As you run the snippet, the boxes will tend to appear one below each other, if you get. How do you make it so that the boxes will stay in one area instead of going down? Like https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrDzR.png. I am trying to achieve my objective in a MyBB environment (custom page with the forum's own default unedited class and stuff). I have tried messing around with width and position, but to no avail. Thanks. I'm also using Font Awesome, if this information helps in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `display: inline-block;` to your css for the divs, it works.

This makes the elements display in one line, and respects the size of the element.

So just `display: inline;` doesn't work, it makes the size of the div go crazy, as seen below.

[image: inline]

But you shouldn't give two elements the same `id`. The value should be unique within the document. You can replace it with a class name.

Answer (score 1):

Div is a block level element. It occupies full width. So next div will always be placed below it.

Adding `display:inline-block;` to `#stitched` will float it next to another.

Here is the link that explains the use of it:
http://joshnh.com/2012/02/07/why-you-should-use-inline-block-when-positioning-elements/

Comment: Worked! ^_^ Thanks! Gotta wait 8 minutes to choose this as the answer. Mind explaining me why inline-block as display type? Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as useful so that its helpful for others facing the same issue.

Comment: your answer would be more helpful with some kind of explanation or reference to inline-block display and maybe a mention of possible caveheat ( actually I only see one: the well known whitespace issue...)

Answer (score 0):

Use: **display: inline-block;**
And set a responsive width of **width:40%;**

```css
#stitched {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  background: grey;
  width: 40%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  border: 2px dashed #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px grey, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
  text-shadow: -1px -1px grey;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <td class="thead"><span class="smalltext"><strong>Player Control Panel</strong></span>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td class="trow1">

      <h1 style="font-size: 35px; text-align: center;">Player Control Panel</h1>

      <div id="stitched">
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-5x" style="text-align: center;"></i>
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">Create your new character account</h2>
      </div>

      <div id="stitched">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-5x" style="text-align: center;"></i>
        <h2 style="text-align: center;">Delete your existing character account</h2>
      </div>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a good idea to give two divs the same id. I gave your second div a separate id. Also [inline-block](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

```css
body{width:100%}
#stitched, #stitched2 {
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 20px;
   margin: 10px;
   background: grey;
   width: 300px;
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 21px;
   font-weight: bold;
   line-height: 1.3em;
   border: 2px dashed #fff;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px grey, 2px 1px 6px 4px rgba(10, 10, 0, 0.5);
   text-shadow: -1px -1px grey;
   font-weight: normal;
}
h1{font-size:35px; text-align:center;}
h2{text-align:center;}
h3{font-size:small;}
```

```html
<body>
    <h3>Player Control Panel</h3>
 <h1>Player Control Center </h1>
 
 <div id="stitched">
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-5x" style="text-align: center;"></i>
  <h2>Create your new character account</h2>
 </div>
 
 <div id="stitched2">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-5x" style="text-align: center;"></i>
  <h2>Delete your existing character account</h2>
 </div>
</body>
```